# Change color of input text when writing on a ion-input with css

Tags: css, ionic-framework, input, sass

I am trying to style a `ion-input` in a way that when there is no text I have a placeholder, if there is text, the text is black, and if I'm typing the text, it is #9933CC.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input placeholder="Last Name" autocapitalize="on" [(ngModel)]="user.lastname" value="{{user.lastname}}"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

This already has the placeholder and ties the value to the model so I'm all good and it works as expected. The problem is that when I type the typing color is always black. This is the piece of CSS I have in my .scss file:

```
input, select, textarea{
  color: #000000;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
  color: #9933CC !important;
}
```

This is what I found in another SO question that apparently helped the person, but it is not working in my case.

Can anybody help? Thank you!

Comment: And what is the class that is causing the colour to be red when you view the output in the browsers inspector?

Comment: There is no red. I want to be able to color the input to #9933CC when I focus on the input, and when I focus out it turns black, that's it.

Comment: I mean open the output in your browser and use the web inspector (f12) and see what is overwriting the `#9933cc` colour on inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that one of the parent items of the `ion-input` has a class assigned named `item-has-focus` which is set when the item is focused. I just needed to define the following in my scss file to make it work:

```
.item-has-focus{
  color: #9933CC !important;
}
```